# Unable to install NLTK on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: python, nltk, macos-high-sierra

This text is to add some extra text to escape the error and has nothing to do with the question. Please excuse!

---

Install:

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

I am getting the following error while installing NLTK on my laptop.

Please help!

### Error

```
 Collecting nltk
 Downloading nltk-3.2.5.tar.gz (1.2MB)
 100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 201kB/s 
 Collecting six (from nltk)
 Downloading six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

 Installing collected packages: six, nltk
 Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
 DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
 Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
 Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
copystat(src, dst)
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)

OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-0HVpKZ uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I tried this command but didn't work

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel (Even this does not install)
```

Comment: `pip install --user --upgrade nltk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best practice to create a virtual environment before installing packages, see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Nevertheless, TL;DR:

```
pip install --user --upgrade nltk
```

Comment: thanks. any more details on why the above is not working?

Comment: In short, Mac don't like `sudo` and Mac prefers `pip install --user`. It's an OS thing; it's handling python packages a little differently from how Linux does things =(

Comment: Perhaps, someone more familiar with Mac quirks can provide you with more information on why `sudo` and `pip` without `--user` is not preferred on Mac.